# Luigi LocalTarget binary file

Tags: python-3.x, luigi

I am having troubles to write a binary `LocalTarget` in a Luigi pipeline in my project. I isolated the problem here:

```
class LuigiTest(luigi.Task):
    def output(self):
        return luigi.LocalTarget('test.npz')

    def run(self):
        with self.output().open('wb') as fout:
            np.savez_compressed(fout, array=np.asarray([1, 2, 3]))
```

I tried opening as `'w'` and `'wb'` but I keep getting the following error:

```
TypeError: write() argument must be str, not bytes
```

I am using python 3.5.1 and my version of luigi is 2.1.1

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The problem was with the format of the `LocalTarget`. Changing it to:

```
return luigi.LocalTarget('test.npz', format=luigi.format.Nop)
```

solved the problem. However there was nothing about this in the documentation.

Comment: Same problem here, very useful!

Answer (score 3):

It solved my problem with writing a parquet file in Hadoop. `format=luigi.format.Nop` did the trick. Thanks!

```
import luigi
import pandas as pd
import luigi.contrib.hdfs as hdfs

class Hdfs(luigi.Task):
    """
    Writes files into output.
    """
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Hdfs, self).__init__( *args, **kwargs)

    def output(self):
        fname_template = f'/data/some_directory/test_luigi.parq'
        return luigi.contrib.hdfs.HdfsTarget(fname_template, format=luigi.format.Nop)

    def run(self):
        with self.output().open('w') as f:
            print(f.path)
            d = pd.DataFrame({'sim_id':[1,2,3]})
            d.to_parquet(f)
```